# Почему собираются файлы только до ifneq?

Tags: makefile

В Android.mk есть такие строки:

```
POLICYVERS ?= 30
sepolicy_build_files := security_classes \
                    initial_sids \
                    access_vectors \
                    global_macros \
                    neverallow_macros \
                    mls_macros \
                    mls \
                    policy_capabilities \
                    te_macros \
                    attributes \
                    ioctl_defines \
                    ioctl_macros \
                    *.te \
                    roles \
                    users \
                    initial_sid_contexts \
                    fs_use \
                    genfs_contexts \
                    port_contexts
```

В файле древа устройства BoardConfig.mk я переопределяю:

```
POLICYVERS = 26
```

Мне нужно что бы при POLICYVERS = 29 и ниже, у нас не собирались ioctl_defines и ioctl_defines

Я использовал примерно такое решение:

```
POLICYVERS ?= 30
sepolicy_build_files := security_classes \
                initial_sids \
                access_vectors \
                global_macros \
                neverallow_macros \
                mls_macros \
                mls \
                policy_capabilities \
                te_macros \
                attributes \
ifeq ($(POLICYVERS),30)
                ioctl_defines \
                ioctl_macros \
endif
                *.te \
                roles \
                users \
                initial_sid_contexts \
                fs_use \
                genfs_contexts \
                port_contexts
```

Но это не работает, точнее собираются только файлы до ifeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно что бы при POLICYVERS = 29 и ниже, у нас не собирались ioctl_defines и ioctl_defines

кажется, это противоположно тому, что вы написали в *makefile*. если так и есть, то вам нужно `ifneq` заменить на `ifeq`

---

я бы рекомендовал использовать условный оператор для **дополнения** строки:

```
POLICYVERS ?= 30
sepolicy_build_files := security_classes \
                initial_sids \
                access_vectors \
                global_macros \
                neverallow_macros \
                mls_macros \
                mls \
                policy_capabilities \
                te_macros \
                attributes \
                *.te \
                roles \
                users \
                initial_sid_contexts \
                fs_use \
                genfs_contexts \
                port_contexts

ifneq ($(POLICYVERS),30)
sepolicy_build_files += \
                ioctl_defines \
                ioctl_macros
endif

all:
  @echo $(sepolicy_build_files) | wc -w
```

теперь при `POLICYVERS` равной `30` в переменной `sepolicy_build_files` будет 17 элементов, а при не равной — 19:

```
$ make
17
$ make POLICYVERS=26
19
```

---

если последовательность элементов существенна, то дополнить можно дважды — первый раз условно, второй раз безусловно:

```
POLICYVERS ?= 30
sepolicy_build_files := security_classes \
                initial_sids \
                access_vectors \
                global_macros \
                neverallow_macros \
                mls_macros \
                mls \
                policy_capabilities \
                te_macros \
                attributes
ifneq ($(POLICYVERS),30)
sepolicy_build_files += \
                ioctl_defines \
                ioctl_macros
endif
sepolicy_build_files += \
                *.te \
                roles \
                users \
                initial_sid_contexts \
                fs_use \
                genfs_contexts \
                port_contexts

all:
  @echo $(sepolicy_build_files) | wc -w
```

---

**по поводу сравнения чисел (больше/меньше)**. операторы `ifeq`/`ifneq` сравнивают строки (равно/не равно). операторы сравнения чисел в программе *make* отсутствуют, и при необходимости сравнения чисел на предмет больше/меньше надо использовать *shell*-функции. например:

```
ifeq ($(shell test $(POLICYVERS) -gt 29; echo $$?),0)
# то, что внутри блока, будет актуально только если
# в переменной POLICYVERS содержится целое число большее 29
endif
```

Comment: Всё правильно не ifneq, а ifeq. В файле Android.mk указывается максимальный sepolicy для данной прошивки, по этому сравнение тут не нужно, но спасибо за информацию. Сработал метод с соблюдением последовательности элементов